# Connector not working on Embedded Jetty SSL when using Tanuki Software WrapperManager

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, tanuki

I have come across a strange issue where SSL configuration of embedded jetty is working fine when i use `server.join()` but is failing when i remove the join code.
I am using `WrapperManager` from tanuki software to make it as a service which needs something to be returned from the `Integer start(String[] args)` method and it is not possible as `server.join` is a blocking call and it wait till the last thread kills.
I am just using regular `SSLConnectionFactory` like below nothing much is added.

```
httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
                    new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConf));
```

Any quick help to resolve the issue is really appreciated.

Comment: Is the JVM that Tanuki software is attempting to manage still running?

Comment: Yes, it was running. i have modified the code to use different HTTPConfiguration objects for HTTP and HTTPS and it started working fine without server.join().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by creating new HTTPConfiguration object for HTTPS. i was using only one object and have passed http port as part of the new server() construtor which is actually causing the issue.
Now the connector HTTP & HTTPS are working fine without server.join()